# Japanese input suddenly broken

Tags: 20.04, input-method, japanese

I'm a Japanese student, and have previously been using Japanese input on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. It was working fine until yesterday, and stopped working earlier today when I rebooted.

## Symptoms

Selecting the Japanese keyboard (either via Super+Space or from the top-right language menu), followed by selecting Hiragana input (top-right language menu, Input Mode, Hiragana). This used to work fine in all apps, but now:

1. Japanese input doesn't work in chrome, gedit, nor the file browser (English is written instead).
2. Japanese input *does* work in the Activities search window (hit Super and type) and in the Run box (Alt+F2)
3. Hebrew input (also configured) *does* work everywhere.

## Potential cause

Looking at /var/log/dpkg.log, I see some packages updated recently:

```
$ cat dpkg.log | awk '/^2020-09-19 13.*status installed.*/ {print}' | sort -u
2020-09-19 13:23:26 status installed bsdutils:amd64 1:2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:27 status installed libsmartcols1:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:28 status installed libblkid1:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:28 status installed libblkid1:i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:28 status installed libmount1:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:28 status installed libmount1:i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:28 status installed libuuid1:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:28 status installed libuuid1:i386 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:30 status installed util-linux:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:33 status installed alsa-ucm-conf:all 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.3
2020-09-19 13:23:33 status installed python3-click:all 7.0-3
2020-09-19 13:23:33 status installed python3-colorama:all 0.4.3-1build1
2020-09-19 13:23:34 status installed grub-common:amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.4
2020-09-19 13:23:34 status installed im-config:all 0.44-1ubuntu1.2
2020-09-19 13:23:34 status installed libfdisk1:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:34 status installed mount:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:34 status installed rfkill:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:34 status installed uuid-dev:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:35 status installed fdisk:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:35 status installed grub2-common:amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.4
2020-09-19 13:23:35 status installed grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.4
2020-09-19 13:23:35 status installed grub-pc-bin:amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.4
2020-09-19 13:23:35 status installed initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 0.136ubuntu6.3
2020-09-19 13:23:35 status installed libblkid-dev:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:35 status installed uuid-runtime:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:38 status installed grub-pc:amd64 2.04-1ubuntu26.4
2020-09-19 13:23:38 status installed initramfs-tools:all 0.136ubuntu6.3
2020-09-19 13:23:38 status installed initramfs-tools-core:all 0.136ubuntu6.3
2020-09-19 13:23:38 status installed libmount-dev:amd64 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1
2020-09-19 13:23:40 status installed grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4
2020-09-19 13:23:40 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9
2020-09-19 13:23:40 status installed systemd:amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.2
2020-09-19 13:23:46 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3
2020-09-19 13:23:46 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
2020-09-19 13:23:46 status installed install-info:amd64 6.7.0.dfsg.2-5
2020-09-19 13:23:46 status installed man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
2020-09-19 13:23:46 status installed mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1
2020-09-19 13:24:02 status installed initramfs-tools:all 0.136ubuntu6.3
```

Package `im-config` ("Input method configuration framework") is particularly suspicious. It was upgraded from `0.44-1ubuntu1.1` to `0.44-1ubuntu1.2` today.

Output of `im-config -m`:

```
default
custom
ibus

ibus
```

BTW, running `im-config` shows a message about manually-modified config being present and preventing the tool from working, in the form of `~/.xinputrc`:

```
$ cat ~/.xinputrc
run_im fcitx
```

I... don't recall putting that there, but it's been there since March (which is likely the first time I configured a Japanese keyboard on this system).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Writing this comment from Google Chrome and ibus-mozc: 柄異あ (don't know what I'm inputting - hope I didn't offend someone). Which tool are you using for inputting Japanese? IBus, Fcitx or something else? Mozc or Anthy? Can you also edit your question and show us what this command outputs: `im-config -m`

Comment: Thank you for checking! I'm not sure which tool I'm using for inputting Japanese; I *think* it's mozc. I'll add the output you requested.

Comment: Are you possibly on Wayland? Can you please try the command `im-config -n REMOVE` and then reboot.

Comment: FYI, mine `.xinputrc` says `# im-config(8) generated on Thu, 28 May 2020 19:57:45 +0900` `run_im fcitx` `# im-config signature: (omit)` That was the day Ubuntu UEFI crashed and I made a fresh install of 20.04 legacy mode from my diary. The file was created at moment I installed `fcitx-mozc` Goed gedaan (I don't know what this means)

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by removing `~/.xinputrc` (which is what `im-config -n REMOVE` appears to do). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good to hear that. Then it was possibly a "regression" from the fix of [bug #1893552](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1893552).